# Issues installing Facebook's Buck

Tags: facebook, build-process, buck

I'm trying to install buck and I'm getting the following error:

```
M00972632:~ blah$ brew install --HEAD buck
==> Installing buck from facebook/homebrew-fb
==> Cloning https://github.com/facebook/buck.git
Updating /Library/Caches/Homebrew/buck--git
==> Checking out branch master
==> ant
==> ./bin/buck build buck
Last 15 lines from /Users/blah/Library/Logs/Homebrew/buck/02.buck:
at com.facebook.buck.shell.Genrule$2.addEnvironmentVariables(Genrule.java:303)
at com.facebook.buck.shell.AbstractGenruleStep.getEnvironmentVariables(AbstractGenruleStep.java:67)
at com.facebook.buck.shell.ShellStep.getDescription(ShellStep.java:231)
at com.facebook.buck.step.DefaultStepRunner.runStepForBuildTarget(DefaultStepRunner.java:56)
at com.facebook.buck.rules.CachingBuildEngine.executeCommandsNowThatDepsAreBuilt(CachingBuildEngine.java:958)
at com.facebook.buck.rules.CachingBuildEngine.access$6(CachingBuildEngine.java:941)
at com.facebook.buck.rules.CachingBuildEngine$1.apply(CachingBuildEngine.java:367)
at com.facebook.buck.rules.CachingBuildEngine$1.apply(CachingBuildEngine.java:1)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$ChainingListenableFuture.run(Futures.java:906)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$1$1.run(Futures.java:635)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[-] BUILDING...FINISHED 3.6s

READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/homebrew):
https://github.com/facebook/homebrew-fb/issues
```

I've made sure to update and install everything the Buck page asks for. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems the same issue was reported and resolved at https://github.com/facebook/buck/issues/429. The error was that the ANDROID_HOME environment variable was pointing to an invalid directory. Unsetting this environment variable resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As @k21 said in the comment to the question, the issue was that `ANDROID_HOME` was set to an invalid directory and so Buck was confused.